# MFC application create WPF control without CLR dependency

Tags: dll, mfc

I want a MFC application can create WPF control without CLR dependency. My solution is to create a MFC regular Dll with CLR dependency which call my WPF control libarary to create a wpf control. The MFC application call this MFC regular Dll to create the wpf control. The problem is when calling the code "HwndSource^ source = gcnew HwndSource(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, name, IntPtr::Zero);", the application throws an exception "**The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this**". I tried several solutions like SetApartmentState, LoadLibrary, CreateThread, Threading::Start and so on, but never of them works.

The MFC Application is a dialog base application, the calling code is：

```
void CMFCApplication1Dlg::OnBnClickedButton1()
{
    CreateCLRControl();
}
```

The MFC regular dll use MFC dll in shared dynamic library, the export function is:

```
void CPPAPI CreateCLRControl()
{
    String^ name = gcnew String("Name");
    HwndSource^ source = gcnew HwndSource(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, name, IntPtr::Zero); // This code will raise the STA ... exception
}
```

Comment: You initialize COM on a thread with the concurrency model set to STA by calling [CoInitialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678543.aspx).

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e91aseaz.aspx